# Get return value of command "mv -n" linux

Tags: shell, mv

From `mv --help`

> `-n, --no-clobber             do not overwrite an existing file`

```
user@pc:~/Desktop/test$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 ago  6 20:28 bla
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 ago  6 20:28 ble
user@pc:~/Desktop/test$ mv -n bla ble
user@pc:~/Desktop/test$
```

Is there a way to check the return value of the command `mv -n`?

Is it possible to do something similar to `$?` to know if the command succeeded (returned 0) in moving the file or failed (returned 1) because there is already another file with the same name in the target folder?

Comment: The exit code will tell you whether the file has been moved/renamed. If you need to programmatically analyze the reason of the failure (in the case of a non-zero exit code), you could parse the error message which is printed by `mv`.

Comment: @user1934428 "The exit code will tell you whether the file has been moved/renamed". That's incorrect to me. Is that how your version of mv behaves? Mine is 8.28 and its documentation states that "a nonzero value indicates failure". Similarly, POSIX states that exit value is non zero when an error ocurred. Aborting the move (with `mv -i` or `mv -n`) is not a failure and my mv exits with 0 accordingly. What version of mv are you using?

Comment: Isn't this the same? My man-page for mv (GNU mv) is silent about the exit code, but it is a common convention, that non-zero means failure, and in the case of a `mv`, failure **is** not having moved, so I thought.  If this is not the case, you could do a `mv -nv` and parse the message written to stdout.

Comment: @user1934428 non-zero does mean failure, but `mv -n foo bar` not moving foo to bar when bar exists is not a failure, the command successfully did what you instructed in  that case and will exit with status zero (success).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `$?` won't tell you if the `-n` option prevented `mv` from doing the move since the exit status will be 0 in this case.

---

Solution 1: you can check that the original file didn't move...

```
mv -n file1 file2
[ -e file1 ] && echo "Hmmm, mv didn't have any effect"
```

However there is a possibility of a race condition if another program recreates file1 in the meantime between the move and your test.

---

Solution 2: since you seem to use GNU `mv`, the `-v` option can be helpful to find out if the move succeeded

```
if mv -v -n file1 file2 | grep -q .; then
    echo "The move succeeded"
fi
```

With `-v`, if the move occurs, `mv` will output `renamed 'file1' -> 'file2'`. Piping its output to `grep -q .` tests whether `mv` output anything on its standard output.

If there is an error, `mv` will output on its standard error and the `grep` will fail too.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it very much. It's much more clear now "mv -n" behavior. I specially liked the second solution, but both are worth.

Comment: `mv -i $f1 $f2 && ! [ -e $f1 ]`

Comment: @aggu Testing the existence of file1 afterwards is covered in my answer and I also explained why this is not an ideal solution

Answer (score 0):

how about comparing time stamp of the files before and after the cmd.
Something similar to: https://github.com/shasan101/bash_for_fun/blob/master/files_comparison_by_time.sh

Comment: This is more a comment to the question than a real answer. To make it a useful answer, you should post an example of code along with your explanation. All in all, your suggestion is not a bad idea, but like my first proposal, this is prone to a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to do the move and then testing for the move failing because the destination file exists, just test for the destination file existing before trying to do the move, e.g.:

```
[[ ! -f ble ]] && mv bla ble || { ret=$?; echo "failed to move bla to ble: $ret" >&2; exit "$ret"; }
```

That will output the error message if ble exists or the mv fails and it exits on a failure, massage to suit, e.g. maybe you'd prefer:

```
[[ -f ble ]] && { ret=$?; echo "warning ble exists so skipping it" >&2; }
[[ $ret == 0 ]] && mv bla ble
```

or a simple if-else:

```
if [[ -f ble ]]; then
    echo "warning ble exists so skipping it" >&2
else
    mv bla ble
fi
```

Comment: Of course! I hadn't thought about this approach. I appreciate, thanks.