# How to redirect existing file to a different directory in linux?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to move files from directory 1 to directory 2, in that process if any file already exists in the destination folder it should instead move the file to directory 3.

I have create a script below but when ever file is skipped using -n parameter the result is true. Can someone let me know how to achieve this ?

```
   #!/bin/bash

    for file in dir1/*; do
      mv -n $file /dir2
      if [ $? != 0 ]; then
       mv $file /dir3
      fi
    done
```

Comment: Here is a related question
https://stackoverflow.com/q/63293165/1328439

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have the following setup

```
mkdir dir{1,2,3}
touch dir1/test{1,2,3}
touch dir2/test2
```

The following code would move `test1` and `test3` to `dir2` and `test2` to `dir3` out of `dir1`

```
for file in dir1/* ; 
do 
   fname="${file##*/}" ; 
   if [ -f "dir2/$fname" ]; then 
      mv "$file" dir3/ ; 
   else 
      mv "$file" dir2/ ; 
   fi 
done
```

Comment: Can you please explain what does this "${file##*/}"   do ?

Comment: @gauravsharma `${file##*/}` is a bash feature. In BASH parameter expansion one can remove a prefix matching a pattern from the value of the variable. Here `*/` is a pattern matching greedily all the directory part of the path thus leaving only the filename. This has the same effect as `$(basename "$file")` where `basename` is a GNU utility that removes the directory component from a path.